# unsupported operand type(s) for ** or pow(): 'ABCMeta' and 'divide'

Tags: python, modeling

I am a beginner trying to set topography for mesh using Gaussian function but got the error in title for line ydel =.

```
# pick depth above which to deform mesh
ydeform = -0.5

yCoordFn = uw.function.input()[1]
xCoordFn = uw.function.input()[0]

#Gaussian bell curve (topography)
ydel = 0.2 * uw.function.math.exp ** (-((xCoordFn - 2.)** 2.) / (2. * 0.2230386** 2.))

if deformedmesh:
    with mesh.deform_mesh():
        for i in range(len(mesh.data[:])):
            y = mesh.data[i,1]
            if y >= ydeform:
                delY = ydel.evaluate((mesh.data[i,0],mesh.data[i,1])) #0.1 * (mesh.data[i,0] + 1.)/2.
                dY = (y - ydeform)/(-ydeform) * delY

                mesh.data[i,1] += dY
```

I have tried to separate the equation to steps like this,

```
def StepA():
    return 2. *( 0.2230386** 2.)
def StepB(): 
    return (xCoordFn - 2.)** 2.
def StepC():
    return StepB / StepA
def StepD():
    return uw.function.math.exp ** -(StepC)

ydel = 0.2 * StepD
```

and this,

```
StepA = 2. * ( 0.2230386** 2.)
StepA = float(StepA)

StepB = (xCoordFn - 2.) ** 2.
StepB = float(StepB)

StepC = StepB/StepA
StepC = float(StepC)

StepD = uw.function.math.exp ** -(StepC)
StepD = float(StepD)

ydel = 0.2 * StepD
```

but they all give similar error for ** of pow() but with function or float, or float argument must be a string or a number.

I have to use the uw.function because of the geodynamic modelling library (underworld2) I am using.

[This is the equation I am trying to use](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MQXDQ.png)

Comment: `exp()` is a *function*.  What are trying to take the exp *of*?

Comment: My assumption is that when you say `uw.function.math.exp ** x`, you really meant to type `uw.function.math.exp( x )`, in each case.  The expression `exp(n)` gives you `e**n`.

Comment: I am basically trying to use the Guassian function equation @jasonharper